# Angular state inspector not working anymore

Tags: angular, google-chrome-devtools

Has anyone came accross this issue. All I remeber is updating chrome but since then the wonderfull add-on [**angular state inspector**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angular-state-inspector/nelkodgfpddgpdbcjinaaalphkfffbem?hl=en) is not working properly. The state tab, which used to show is empty. I  have looked around for a solution but no one seems to have reported this anywhere.I am using  Chrome Version 92.0.4515.10 , angular 11 and 9.  I also tried in edge and got the same issue.
I thought it was because angular build was by default using production enviroment config, but it wasn't the case. Specifying development configutation on the build command did not help.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I have just tried on a ealier version of Chrome and everything works fine. As soon as I update to Version 92.0.4515.10, it breaks. It must be something in the new version of chrome that doesn't work well with the tool. I have reported the issue to both Chrome and extention developer

Comment: same problem here, I upvote it, let's see if Chrome gets an update to fix it or what.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's caused by recent chrome update https://github.com/anton-lunev/angular-state-inspector/issues/17

The worksround is to select element in chrome dev tools and run `$state` in console. it returns the state of selected node

Comment: Thanks! The workaround worked fine actully. It's a litle inconvenient but I am so happy I can debug the state again instead of guessing. Hope they fix the issue. I dunno if I should Close this question

Answer (score 0):

Angular DevTools seems to do the job quite well : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angular-devtools/ienfalfjdbdpebioblfackkekamfmbnh

Looks like an official Angular extension

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged here. Links can break over time rendering the answer meaningless. Please summarize the linked information to help future readers.

Comment: Thanks for that. That's the official Angular extension, It's good for profiling howerver it's not so good for inspecting states. For example it won't show components that were dynimicaly injected at runtime.  I  used both Angular State Inspector and Angular DevTools  and there are things Angular DevTools doesn't do yet that are great in Angular State Inspector

Answer (score 0):

The angular devTools will not work with angularJs applications.
Developing with ServiceNow service portal, which is reliant on angularJS 1.6x, has become exceedingly more difficult without being able to use angular inspector.